# Allow/block the incoming request based on the request header in IIS/Sharepoint server

Tags: iis-7, sharepoint-2010, http-headers

I have sharepoint sites running on IIS 7.5 . I want to allow/block the incoming request based on the request header .This is the condition i want to implement

Here clientId and userAgent are the request Headers.

```
String clientId=Request.getHeaderValue('clientID');
String userAgent=Request.getHeaderValue('useragent');

//If clientId and userAgent are empty abort the request

 if(clientId.equals('') && userAgent.equals('')){

//Abort the request
} 

//If clientId is not empty but is not matching my expected value,then abort the    request.
if(!clientId.equals('') && !clientId.equals('1234'){

//Abort the request
}

//If userAgent is not matching my expected value ,then abort the request.
if(!userAgent.equals('myfavbroswer')){

//Abort the request

}
```

I have already taken a look at URLRewriteModule in IIS.It doesn't seem to serve my purpose.

This is the rough logic i want to put in place.I am new to IIS server and sharepoint.Can some one tell me where i can put this logic to server my purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URLRewrite actually serves my purpose.You just need to know how to use it.I just needed to write my condition in a different way.It allows you to make any conditions you want.Only thing is it is a bit confusing in the beginning.Also If you know regexp then it becomes a very good module to use.

Edit:This video gives you a very good understanding of how to achieve this.
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-video-walkthrough

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some explanation about how you solved the problem. I am interested in blocking based on http headers.

Comment: Please go through the video